# determinant of positive semidefinite

Tags: linear-algebra

From the description of positive semidefinite matrix, I found that determinant of positive semidefinite is multiplication of its eigenvalues. Can anyone show me how to derive this property?

Comment: Hint: Eigenvalue decomposition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This holds for all matrices. Suppose that $\mathbf M \in \mathbb{F}^{n,n}$ is a matrix. Its eigenvalues $(\lambda_k)_{k=0}^{n-1}$ are roots of the characteristic polynomial
$$ \det (\lambda \mathbf I - \mathbf M) = c \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (\lambda_k - \lambda)
$$
Expanding along the diagonal shows that the leading coefficient is $c = 1$. Therefore you can set $\lambda = 0$ to obtain the desired result.

Comment: Thank you for information. Can you explain me again the rationale behind setting c = 1 & λ=0?

Comment: @pippp Every polynomial can be factored, and the leading coefficient can vary. In this case the leading coefficient $c$ is $1$. We can set $\lambda = 0$ since $\lambda$ is an arbitrary variable.

Answer (score 1):

The determinant of any matrix $M$ is the constant term of the characteristic polynomial $\det(M - \lambda I)$, and thus the product of the roots of that polynomial, which are the eigenvalues (counted by algebraic multiplicity).

Comment: As long as the characteristic polynomial factorizes...

Comment: Over a splitting field, it does.  The OP mentioned "positive semidefinite", so in this case the field can be $\mathbb R$.

Comment: yes. I think it is a fact worth to mention.